# Many to many relationship mapping using AutoMapper in .net core

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a problem with the many to many relationship mapping, I have the following data:

```
public partial class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthor>();
    }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}

public partial class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
  BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthor>();
    }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int NoOfPages { get; set; }
    public decimal StarRating { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}

public partial class BookAuthor
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorDto
{

public int AuthorId { get; set; }
public string AuthorName { get; set; }
public string Nationality { get; set; }
public string Biography { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }

public IList<BookDto> Books { get; set; }
}

public class BookDto
{
public int BookId { get; set; }
public bool Title { get; set; }
public string Isbn { get; set; }
public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public int NoOfPages { get; set; }
public decimal StarRating { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

public IList<AuthorDto> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping code :

```
CreateMap<Author, AuthorDto>().ForMember(dto => dto.Books, opt =>  
pt.MapFrom(x => x.BookAuthors.Select(y => y.Book).ToList()));

CreateMap<Book, BookDto>().ForMember(dto => dto.Authors, opt => 
opt.MapFrom(x => x.BookAuthors.Select(y => y.Author).ToList()));

CreateMap<BookAuthor, AuthorDto>();
CreateMap<BookAuthor, BookDto>();
```

If I try to obtain the books I receive: 
"Type Map configuration:
Book -> BookDto
BooksSinglePageApplication.Models.Book -> BooksSinglePageApplication.Dtos.BookDto

Property:
Title ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)...."

and if I try to obtain the authors I receive:
"Mapping types:
List`1 -> IList`1
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[BooksSinglePageApplication.Models.Author, BooksSinglePageApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[BooksSinglePageApplication.Dtos.BookDto, BooksSinglePageApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException:
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Author -> BookDto (Destination member list)
BooksSinglePageApplication.Models.Author -> BooksSinglePageApplication.Dtos.BookDto (Destination member list)"

I know that there are similar questions already asked, I checked them and tried everything, I really don't know what else to try.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: One problem is BookDto.Title should be string rather than bool.

Comment: Also this mapping doesn’t make much sense all together.  You seem to be trying to map unrelated types. Author -> BookDto rather than Book -> BookDto.

Comment: I saw now that Title was declared as bool in BookDto...it works, but getting the authors is still not possible, I don't see where it tries to map Author to BookDto. Thank you very much !

Comment: I found the problem, in AuthorsController I had                                     
    var authorDtos = _mapper.Map<IList<BookDto>>(authors)                  
 ,I am dumb, thanks for your help !